# Propositional Logic Question

Tags: logic

I have to convert an english sentence into a symbolic notation. I think I have this correct but I want to know if it is correct...I think it's right because I did it so that

$P$ = "Brad went to the park"
$Q$ = "Brad got ice cream"
$R$ = "Brad's family went to the park"

Either Brad went to the park, or Brad got ice cream and his family did not go to the park on Saturday.

$P \vee (Q \wedge \neg R)$

I'm assuming that by having Brad on the left side of the sentence before the conjunction "or" and having $Q$ and $R$ both after the or that this is correct notation.

I was also told that for clarification this is like "$A$ or $B$, but not both" and I think that's what threw me off.

EDIT: Ok thanks for your help. But I think now I'm just really confused. IF you say "or" can't it just be assumed that it's one or the other? what is it in the logic that produces the possibility that both can occur.

Comment: If the or is exclusive then you need to add more to make it  correct.

Comment: how do you know if the "or" is exclusive

Comment: "Not both" is what tells you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment your answer gives the inclusive reading of or (i.e. both can be correct) as $\lor$ is inclusive or. So, you need to exclude the case where both $P$ and $(Q\land \neg R)$ are true. You could tack on to your sentence $$\cdots \land \neg (P \land (Q \land \neg R))$$
So then what you have says "at least one of" and the bit you add says "not both".

Another way of doing it is to say you are in one of the cases where precisely one is true i.e. $$(P \land \neg (Q \land \neg R))\lor (\neg P \land (Q\land \neg R))$$
Here the inclusive $\lor$ in the middle isn't a problem, because if both disjuncts are true, the both $P$ and $\neg P$ are true, which is contradictory.